# Is it possible to draw closed shapes in Dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I know that closed shapes are not functions, because there can be more than one `y` value for each `x` value. The easiest example is a circumference.

I was wondering if it's possible to draw a closed shape in dygraphs.
Basically what i would love to do is to draw a path with Dygraph using a list of GPS points.

I tried simply to give those GPS point to dygraphs, but unfortunately nothing good came out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dygraphs is designed for rendering time series and data sets that look like time series. It's not particularly good at scatter plots like yours.

If you really want to give it a shot, here's one idea: make a data set where the three columns are point number, latitude and longitude. dygraphs will think that point number is the x-axis but you can trick it by setting both `dateWindow` (to control the x-axis range) and `valueRange` (to control the y-axis range). Then you'll need to write a [custom plotter](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html) to draw the closed shape using the latitudes and longitudes.